# How much space do I need to fit 1 million people in an isolated city?

Tags: medieval

Imagine an isolated circle-shaped city in a medieval setting. Within this circle is another circle, where the Highborn are living (around 100k people).  Common folk (around 900k people) lives on the outter circle, where they are working. My question is, how much space in km^2 or square miles do I need to have in the outter circle for living space, working space, farmland, livestock etc.?

Resources such as water and firewood will be dealt with with magic. I just want to have a rough idea of how much space I need.

Comment: The main question with isolated medieval cities is always how you get food and other resources (like firewood) in. That's why cities were usually surrounded by vast swathes of farms and managed woodland

Comment: @biziclop I just wanna have a rough idea of how much space I need. Resources such as firewood will be dealt with magic or something

Comment: I think that's worth adding to the question then, to avoid answers about stuff you're not interested in.

Comment: Do you care about realism? In medieval times France or Italy had a total of about 14 million inhabitants.

Comment: What kind of information have you found already? I mean, a quick google search reveals the answer to the question.

Comment: @elemtilas I haven‘t found anything online, do you mind sharing some links?

Comment: @L.Dutch I sort of care about realism, the living space in the outter circle shouldn‘t be comfortable, which will eventually lead to a massive protest.

Comment: Um. I literally googled largest medieval city. You can take your pick from Constantinople to Cairo to Kaifeng. Also, you might want to consider offering some guidelines for the kind of answer you want. You don't specify how built up a place you're looking for, how many parks and public spaces, how broad the streets, etc. Basically what population density are you looking to achieve?

Comment: One thing you might consider is putting this question in the Sandbox (in Meta), rather than posting here in Main, since it seems like you're kind of vague on important details and prior research! As expressed, there are literally 689 entirely different and equally valid answers to this question, and that's not the kind of question SE is looking for.

Comment: "where the Highborn are living (around 100k people)" - if by Highborn you mean the nobles, i.e. dynastic medieval landowners, that's way way too many - it gives a ratio of 1 noble per 10 non nobles - the servants alone would be more than 10 per 1. Besides, the nobles wouldn't all live in the city. If the 100k are simply wealthy citizens who can afford better housing, such as merchants or wealthy craftsmen, and a small number of minor nobles, that would be more realistic.

Comment: If water and firewood are produced by magic, can they not do the same with food, making livestock and farmland unnecessary?

Comment: It's generally considered very bad form to award the green checkmark so soon after asking a question. Especially when there are problems with your question in need of clarification. You're literally telling us nothing at all about the world you're building, nothing about the people that will live in this city.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how much space in km^2 or square miles do I need to have in the outter circle for living space, working space, farmland, livestock etc.?

-- that depends very strongly on climate, soils, the general geography etc., but generally the medieval population densities in Europe ran from 10 to 100 people per sq km, or 25 to 250 per sq mile. So for your 900 thousand commoners, you would need somewhere between 9,000 and 90,000 sq km, or 3,500 to 35,000 sq miles. If they were uniformly spread over a circle centered on the Highborn city, their settlements would stretch away from it to a radius of 50-170 km, or 30-100 miles.